# Exporting video from processing 3

Tags: audio, video, processing, visualization

I am using processing-3.2.2 for audio visualization. I have the code to play the visualiser but I don't know how to save it as a video(.mp4) file.

Here's what I wrote:

```java
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;
AudioMetaData meta;
BeatDetect beat;
int  r = 200;
float rad = 70;
void setup()
{
  size(500, 500);
  //size(600, 400);
  minim = new Minim(this);
  player = minim.loadFile("son_final.mp3");
  meta = player.getMetaData();
  beat = new BeatDetect();
  player.play();
  //player.play();
  background(-1);
  noCursor();
}

void draw()
{ 
  float t = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, 1);
  beat.detect(player.mix);
  fill(#1A1F18,50);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  noFill();
  fill(-2, 10);
  if (beat.isOnset()) rad = rad*0.9;
  else rad = 70;
  ellipse(0, 0, 2*rad, 2*rad);
  stroke(-1, 50);
  int bsize = player.bufferSize();
  for (int i = 0; i < bsize - 1; i+=5)
  {
    float x = (r)*cos(i*2*PI/bsize);
    float y = (r)*sin(i*2*PI/bsize);
    float x2 = (r + player.left.get(i)*100)*cos(i*2*PI/bsize);
    float y2 = (r + player.left.get(i)*100)*sin(i*2*PI/bsize);
    line(x, y, x2, y2);
  }
  beginShape();
  noFill();
  stroke(-1, 50);
  for (int i = 0; i < bsize; i+=30)
  {
    float x2 = (r + player.left.get(i)*100)*cos(i*2*PI/bsize);
    float y2 = (r + player.left.get(i)*100)*sin(i*2*PI/bsize);
    vertex(x2, y2);
    pushStyle();
    stroke(-5);
    strokeWeight(2);
    point(x2, y2);
    popStyle();
  }
  endShape();
   if (flag) showMeta();
}


void showMeta() {
  int time =  meta.length();
  textSize(50);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text( (int)(time/1000-millis()/1000)/60 + ":"+ (time/1000-millis()/1000)%60, -7, 21);
}

boolean flag =false;
void mousePressed() {
  if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, width/2, height/2)<150) flag =!flag;
}

void keyPressed() {
  if(key=='e')exit();
}
```

I know I can import MovieMaker library but I don't know how to use it in this code. Please suggest some changes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Video Export library for that. More info here: http://funprogramming.org/VideoExport-for-Processing/

Then all you'd do is create an instance of `VideoExport` and then call `videoExport.saveFrame()` at the end of your `draw()` function.

```
import com.hamoid.*;

VideoExport videoExport;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);

  videoExport = new VideoExport(this, "basic.mp4");
}
void draw() {
  background(#224488);
  rect(frameCount * frameCount % width, 0, 40, height);

  videoExport.saveFrame();
}
```

There are a ton of resources online. I recommend googling "Processing video export" for a ton of results. Then try something out and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (not your entire project) showing exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: Hey @KevinWorkman I made the changes and It does export the .mp4 video file but have no audio in it!

Comment: @ShivamSharma I really recommend doing some research. Google "Processing video export sound" to see how other people have done it. Try something out, and then post a specific question if you get stuck. Good luck.